# Java money and ratios, how to store and manipulate?

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal

I've been trying to refactor a real time application that uses `BigDecimal`, to a fixed point representation with 10 decimal digits using a `long`, as it's what is commonly advised to store and manipulate money in Java. The problem is I need to deal with ratios as well (exchange rates, discount rates, percentages, etc) and I'm not sure how to do that in a sane way.

So to create those decimals I do this (encapsulated in a class of course):

```
long multiplier = (long) Math.pow(10, precision)
long decimal = 1.2345 * multiplier; // 12345000000
```

Here are some basic operations with this representation:

```
long addition       = decimal1 + decimal2;
long subtraction    = decimal1 - decimal2;
long multiplication = (decimal1 * decimal2) / multiplier;
long division       = (decimal1 * multiplier) / decimal2;
```

As you can see, multiplications and divisions written like that are prone to overflows even for small numbers. That reduces the range of valid arguments for these operations greatly.

So some may ask why do you need that in the first place? Well, to convert from a currency to another for instance: `eur=usd*rate`, or to get the return of an investment: `roi=profit/investment`.

What is the real way to go to get good accuracy up to a certain number of digits and excellent performance (as close as possible to using primitive types)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `long multiplication = (decimal1 * decimal2) / multiplier?` i.e. **divide by multiplier**. Say `decimal1` and `decimal2` both represent `1`, so their values are both `10^10`. Then the result should represent `1` (i.e. be `10^10`) too, so you should divide by multiplier: `(10^10 * 10^10) / 10^10 = 10^10`.

Comment: True, that was a typo.

Comment: You could write code that handles the overflow that might occur when you multiply two `long` values. Roughly, you split the operands in half, and do 64-bit operations on 32-bit operands. But this is what `BigDecimal` is doing internally. The main difference would be that `BigDecimal` uses some loops to support arbitrary precision; since you have fixed precision, you could unroll these. Would that have a significant performance benefit? It would introduce a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Use primitive types and store cents (not dollars/euros/whatever)!

That’s what banks do, and what you should do too.

Putting a decimal point in a number is a *rendering* issue; don’t let rendering influence your core data type.

A `long` of cents will accurately hold the total global debt thousands of times over - it’s big enough to hold any value you will ever encounter.

Comment: If I store cents (or whatever the smallest unit in that currency is) I still need to convert them to BigDecimal before applying an exchange rate right? For instance, 1234 cents multiplied by 10 jpy/usd would be done as BigDecimal.valueOf(1234, 100).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(10)).longValue(). That is slower than using only BigDecimals for everything, which is what I currently use. Is this correct? If that is the case, why banks use longs and not something similar to BigDecimal with an appropriate scale?

Comment: @Matt use the exchange rate expressed as cents to cents and you’ll get nearest cent accuracy.

Comment: Following what you recommended, 10 jpy/usd equals 0.1 jpy/cent, but that doesn't fix the problem. Suppose I have 1230 cents and 0.1 is actually 0.0999999999. So how many jpy do I have? `(long) 1230*0.09999999` which is equal to 122. I guess the correct way of doing this is by storing cents and always round (not truncate) like with Math.round(1230 * 0.0999999999). That works, but it won't in some other cases (for instance if I start with 1229 cents). It would be nice if you can explain further, since this is what I mostly do (currency conversions).

Comment: @Matrix Look at it anohter way: By storing cents, you're storing 100 times the number of dollars. The multiplier is how many demical places of accuracy you want. So store 100 times the number of Yen. Or store 1000000 times the bank note currency (eg dollars, yen, etc) for all countries and forget about "cents" - just render 2 decimal places for dollars and none for yen. Rounding issues can be taken care of by formatters. By doing this you'll have lightning fast conversions and simple storage.

Comment: I seriously don't know how that will help me. You're proposing I store all currencies with the same multiplier right? So instead of 1230 usd cents and 1 jpy I would have 12300000 for usd and 1000000 for jpy? Then again, the conversion would be 10.0 jpy/usd, which may be slightly off, so I either get 122000000 or 123000000 jpy. Same problem. Let me know if I'm wrong, I'm probably missing your point.

Comment: Err. I would get 122999999 or 130000000. Which I can round later. I guess that would work if I choose a multiplier big enough for all currencies. However, how is this different than working with doubles and not having any multiplier in the first place? Errors would sum up equally bad.

Comment: @Matrix store amounts in `long` (100% accurate), use `double` exchange rates, multiply amounts by exchange rate then convert that answer to `long`, rounding (slightly slower) if required, or casting (super fast, but truncating the fractional part)

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't make sense.

1. You only multiply money by scalars. It is meaningless to multiply two money amounts together. What exactly are you expecting? Square money?
2. The result of dividing a money amount by another is not a money amount. It is a ratio, e.g. an exchange rate.

NB a `long` holds a lot more than 10 decimal digits. More like 20 offhand.

Comment: 1. I'm not trying to multiply two money amounts together, but a money amount times a ratio (or else two ratios). All these values would be stored in this representation using longs as it's much faster than BD. I edited the question so it's not confusing.

2. That's right, the resulting value is a ratio, and I don't want it in a double for the same reason I don't want money in a double. What is your point?

Comment: I don't find that stated anywhere in your question.